# Sorting/Filtering multiple tables in Excel

Tags: excel

I have multiple tables in Excel. They have the same column headers. An example is below:

```
          A  B  C

John      4  5  6   

Mary      1  3  5

Tom       2  9  10




          A  B  C

John      4  6  7

Mary      8  10  12

Tom       11  4  3
```

Is there way to individually filter each table in the same spreadsheet by column C (largest to smallest)? It seems that I can filter the first table fine, but the second I cannot.

Comment: How are you filtering?  You should be able to select the whole table and right click -> sort -> custom sort, then select the other table and right click -> sort -> custom sort.

Comment: @PortlandRunner: I am just clicking the Sort and Filter tab. I am using Microsoft Excel 2010.

Comment: Okay, the key may be what you are selecting before you hit 'sort' see my answer below.

Comment: FYI - This is a better question for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/) since it's not directly related to programming.

Comment: @PortlandRunner: Perhaps macros may be involved.

Answer (score 0):

Select your first table (all columns and rows), right click and select 'sort', then select 'Custom Sort'.

[image]

Now you can sort by column C, values, and smallest to largest.

[image]

Now select your other range and do the same steps as above.

[image]

---

***edit***

You can have a named cell in one table:

[image]

Referenced by another table:

[image]

And still be able to sort as mentioned above.

Comment: Would this work if the tables were next to each other instead on top of each other?

Comment: Yes, it will work with what you select before you hit sort.  Make sure you only select the data you want sorted.

Comment: The names on the first table are referencing cells in other sheets. The names of the second table are just the values. Would this make a difference?

Comment: See my edited post above.  I was able to name a cell in one table and link it to another table via formula, sort by column 'C' and maintain the formula link.